# Change default "/public" to "public_html" in production

Tags: php, laravel, server, storage

I'm putting my Laravel project in production and I've clone it from GitHub to `/home/myuser/repositories/myuser/MYPROJECT-app`, and my public Laravel folder content is in `/home/myuser/public_html`.

I've changed `(project location)/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` and add:

```
$this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return '/home/myuser/public_html';
});
```

To the `Register` function. I changed the `index.php` from the public folder to match my project location and everything works well, except when I try to upload a file using the method:

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('myfiles/', $request->myFile)
```

It is stored in `/home/myuser/repositories/MYPROJECT-app/public/storage/myfiles` instead of `/home/myuser/public_html/storage/myfiles`.

(Note: I cannot use symbolic links because some restrictions with the server configuration, so I'm trying to store all the files within a `storage` folder within the public path).

I'm guessing I'm missing some configuration to tell Laravel to store the uploaded files in `/public_html/storage` instead of `MYPROJECT/public/storage`, but I can't find which file I have to change.

Comment: Based on experience, if you are not able to solve this yourself, then don't do this change, you are changing something core from the framework and if you do it wrongly, you could have lot of issues... why do you need to do this change?

Comment: how about changing where your domain points to in cPanel or something

Comment: Why should I try to change where my domain points to in cPanel? it has nothing to do with it. The issue here is that my Laravel project configuration is set to the "public" folder within the project by default, but my public content is outside the Laravel project folder. I'm trying to find a way to set the public storage driver default location outside the project, so that the function that stores the files (Storage::disk('public)->put(...)) stores them in the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, but I cannot assure it 100%. (I will be using Laravel 9.x).

In your `config/filesystems.php`, go to the `disks` index and add a new one just for testing purposes:

```php
'outside' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => realpath('/home/myuser/public_html'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
    'throw' => false,
],
```

As you can see, we are using `realpath('/home/myuser/public_html')`, but have in mind that `url` requires a symlink and you said it is not possible, so you are basically done there.

Let me know if this partially works, does it works but the URL not? Can you read files, store them, etc?

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll try it next week in my work and I'll tell if it works.